# how to pass domain name through load balancer nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

i have a load balancer with nginx and pass traffic to other servers.
everything is working fine but i am allowing my clients to add their own custom domain name or use a subdomain from my domain and i can't get the domain name from the servers handling the requests.
is there a way i can pass the domain name from the load balancer to the servers.
now in the sever i just get the name of the upstream

```
upstream backend {
        server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

interested of the domain name i get backend.

thank you

Comment: server name is missing in the configuration. how should nginx know, what content should be served?

Comment: i didn't post the whole config i posted only the part that has anything to do with the question. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTTP upstream, you can simply use `proxy_set_header`, as below

```
upstream backend {
        server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://backend;
        proxy_set_header  Host "the domain name you wanted";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i am looking for .